# How to Connect Fender Champion 20 Amp to the Bluetooth Beats Studio 3 Headset

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers, headphones, pre-amp, amplification

I have Fender Champion 20 amp.
I want to connect amp to the beats studio headset.
I found [Bluetooth Aux Kit](https://www.hepsiburada.com/pratik-bluetooth-aux-arac-kiti-p-HBV000008706Z?magaza=ISTA%20MARKET). Is it enough? If not what do you suggest.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest a wired set of headphones.

Bluetooth has a delay/latency that you just wouldn't care about when listening to iTunes etc, but it will drive you mad playing guitar.

Comment: I have wired headphones, i tried to connect before. yes it's efficient, but i want to try with wireless.

Comment: Well, your question said "if not, what do you suggest?" I suggest not wasting your money ;))

Comment: thank you, do you have any suggestions about the device?

Comment: Best Buy recycles electronics to keep em out of the landfill.